# Localhost issue with Polymer demo app

Tags: python, localhost, polymer

I am just trying to learn Polymer framework. I've downloaded the sample app from polymer-project.org and have followed all the initial setup steps mentioned at https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html but when i try to run the localhost test page as mentioned there, i get error saying **This webpage is not available**.

Am i missing something with localhost? I have downloaded and installed Python 3x for Windows. Do i need any virutal server setup like we do in php (WAMP/XAMPP for example)?

Here is a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/f27fh78h3/) of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to run local server, and give a try to port `80`, instead of `8000`

Comment: Thank you Eugene!

But weirdly, it works on XAMPP server which is a php localhost server, isn't it strange? I mean this Polymer thing is altogether different from all things php.

Any other recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the web server setup described in https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html ?

Running the Python webserver in the root directory of the project with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

or with Python 3 :

```
python -m http.server
```

and verifying it works by going to

```
http://localhost:8000/finished/
```

Polymer app need to be served by a webserver, any webserver serving static content will work, either this small Python server, or an Apache HTTPd or any WAMP/LAMP setup.

Comment: I actually downloaded and installed Python 3, tried to run that command from Python command prompt but was getting error, so just tried XAMPP and it worked!